# qt translator doesn't show translated text in program

Tags: qt, multilingual, qt-linguist

I use qt linguist to translate my program in different languages but it doesn't show he translated text in the program.
I set proper fonts and add .ts file to `TRANSLATIONS`.

I use `lupdate` and `lrelease` commands.

how can i create .ts file also? (I create text file and change the format to .ts is it correct way?)

Comment: did you load translation to application? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#installTranslator http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#load

Comment: yes. I load .ts files and .qm files

Comment: there is a lot stuff to do to have translation active. Your problem description is to simple to short and incomplete. Just follow instruction from Qt and make sure you didn't miss anything. Check also logs maybe there Qt reports some error.

Answer (score 5):

Revie [Qt Translation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html).

To translate the app dynamically:

1 - Open Qt command terminal and go to your project folder.
2 - Get all the translatable string from your project

```
lupdate -pro Example.pro -ts example.ts
```

3 - Translate all the string to the language you want using QLinguist
4 - Generate the .qm file with all translation executing:

```
lrelease example.ts
```

5 - Add this file, example.qm, as a resource to your project to include it with the executable file. [Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

6 - Now, use [QTranslator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html) to translate the app:

```
QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator;
if(translator->load(":/"+example.qm)){
    qApp->removeTranslator(translator); // Remove the translator if was used before
    qApp->installTranslator(translator); // Install again the translator to force a new translation.
    qDebug() << "Translation success!" ;
}else{
    qDebug() << "Error file not found!";
}
```

7 - You can handle the translation event using changeEvent:

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
     if (event) {
          switch(event->type()) {
              // When the translator is loaded this event is send.
              case QEvent::LanguageChange:
                    break;
              // Whem the system language changes this event is send.
              case QEvent::LocaleChange:
                    //retranslate the ui.
                    break;
              default:
                    break;
          }
     }
     QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);
}
```

That's all folks!

Comment: If you are running Qt in Windows, open your qt program folder an look for the Qt  MVSC/MinGW  command promp

Comment: where do you load your font?
I think i can't load my font

Comment: +1 I stuck this for hours, can't see translated text. Turn out only way is to put `.qm` file inside resource file, otherwise won't work.